# How to limit the texbox to accept only numbers and backspace?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, winforms

I have to create a textbox which will ignore all the non numeric input. 
I tried to use this code which I found in this site

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
            e.Handled = Not Char.IsDigit(e.Keychar)
End Sub
```

But I have a mistake in this part of the code `System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code you have is for WinForms, not ASP.NET. In ASP.NET you would have to use client-scripting to restrict textbox input, or handle a postback event for each keypress (hint: do not do this).

Comment: This won't allow backspace.Better use Regular expression for your case.

Comment: and how to restrict it in asp?

Comment: can it be done using vb only?

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps

```
  Sub btnDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyPress

    if e.KeyChar= Chr(8)
       'do something for backspace
    else if e.KeyChar=(CHr(13)
       'do something for enter
    end if
    end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dai
Key stroke in ASP.net SHOULD ALWAYS be managed on the client side to avoid unecessary postback an avoid overloading server .
If you are not familiar with Javascript you can refer to this excelleent tutorial from W3School to manage the onChangeEvent of an input

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

If you really want to manage the key 'on fly', you can manage the  'onkeyDown' event
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use this in code-behind

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(yourStringToValidate,"^[a-zA-Z0-9\\\$]+$")
{
   //Place your msg
}
else
{
 //Place your validation msg
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/DA-DK/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) and set the mask to some thing like this:

```
maskedTextBox1.Mask = "\d*";
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should be placed within  head section of html.

I have used Jquery library to validate purpose

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mytext').keydown(function(e) {

                if (e.shiftKey) e.preventDefault();
                else {
                    var nKeyCode = e.keyCode;
                    //Ignore Backspace and Tab keys
                    if (nKeyCode == 8 || nKeyCode == 9) return;
                    if (nKeyCode < 95) {
                        if (nKeyCode < 48 || nKeyCode > 57) e.preventDefault();
                    } else {
                        if (nKeyCode < 96 || nKeyCode > 105) e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }

            });
        });

    </script>
```

Html code

```
<input type="text" id="mytext">
```